# Python not finding function from separate file

Tags: python, function

I have two files.

The first file resides in the base directory: 
main_file.py

The Second File resides in base-directory/helpers/file_with_functions.py

When I try to call the function in the main_file.py using:

```
from helpers import *
```

I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'"

I've also tried:

```
from helpers.file_with_functions import *
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the latest version of Python.

Comment: As an aside, asterisk imports are a bad idea.

Comment: As @Chris implies, similar questions have been asked regularly - but the TLDR here should be to use the code in your second excerpt but make sure there is an (empty) file called `__init__.py` in your `helpers` directory.